# Fill NAs by matching columns within groups in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to replace NAs in a column with a matching value from a different group in the same column.

**Sample data**

```
data = data.frame(groupID = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4)),
              date = seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), by = "day", length.out = 4),
              value = c(1, 2, 3, NA, 7, NA, 9, 10))

# groupID date       value
# A       2000-01-01     1
# A       2000-01-02     2
# A       2000-01-03     3
# A       2000-01-04    NA
# B       2000-01-01     7
# B       2000-01-02    NA
# B       2000-01-03     9
# B       2000-01-04    10
```

The `value` column has missing data that should be filled by data with the same time stamp (from `date`column) but from the other group, i.e. missing data from `groupID` `A` should be replaced with the corresponding value from group `B`, and vice versa.

**Desired Output**

```
# groupID date       value
# A       2000-01-01     1
# A       2000-01-02     2
# A       2000-01-03     3
# A       2000-01-04    10
# B       2000-01-01     7
# B       2000-01-02     2
# B       2000-01-03     9
# B       2000-01-04    10
```

**What I tried**

I am trying to keep my data tidy but the only working method I came up with was to spread the data by groupID, then mutate with `ifelse` (or `case_when`), and gather the data again, as below:

```
data %>% 
  spread(., key = groupID, value = value) %>%
  mutate(., A = ifelse(is.na(A), B, A),
            B = ifelse(is.na(B), A, B)) %>%
  gather(., key = "groupID", value = "value", -date)
```

**What I would like to have**

But since there are >2 groups in the data set and >1 value columns to be processed, I would love to have an alternative that I can use within the mutate call in the pipe without the spread/gather step.

- In general, is there a way to group by `groupID` and then call mutate in combination with, say, `case_when` or similar where the RHS is matching `value` by `date`?
- More specifically, is there a straightforward way to use a function in the `mutate` that would let me specify a preferred ranking of groupIDs to gap fill from? Say, we have groups A, B, C, D and there are missing values in A that should be gap filled first by group C (if available), then by group D (if available), and never by a value in group D?

Comment: Try `data %>% group_by(date) %>% mutate(value = value[!is.na(value)])` or may be `data %>% group_by(date) %>% fill(value) %>% fill(value, .direction = 'up')`

Comment: `mydata %>% group_by(date) %>% mutate(value = ifelse(is.na(value), mean(value, na.rm =TRUE), value))` maybe a bit more robust as will work for many groups or observations per date.

Comment: The first solution proposed by @akrun works perfectly for the sample data but unfortunately not for my "real" data with more than two groups, it throws an error `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Column `value` must be length 3 (the group size) or one, not 2` when used with groups A, B, C; the second solution works for more than two groups but needs more than one minute to process about 13K rows on my machine.

Comment: The code in the comment by @StephenHenderson works with more groups like a charm. Is there a straightforward way to use a function in the ìfelse` that would let me specify a preferred ranking of groupIDs to gap fill from? Say, we have groups A, B, C, D and there are missing values in A that should be gap filled first by group C (if available), then by group D (if available), and never by a value in group D?

Comment: Yes. You should probably edit the question. And I'll post an answer. Although do you mean actually D specifically or just the last in the series e.g could be F, G if there were that many groups?

Comment: Thanks @StephenHenderson. The question is now extended. Oh, and I mean "D" specifically; it is not necessarily the last entry in the factor levels. To be exact, I have several groupIDs (coding for locations) and I would like to gap fill observations with available data from other, close-by, locations but not with data from locations that are relatively far away.

Comment: and you would be fine with a single preference ranking, or it would basically depend on the group you are trying to fill values for?

Comment: @RolandASc it would depend on the group